# Active Directory - Create Computer into container with 'Everyone' ACL

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, acl

I am currently still beginning to understand Active Directory, I am able to add domain groups into local administrator group but I would like to understand how to approach this : I need to create a computer into the right container in my domain, which I understand how to achieve this, but I do not understand how I can be able to achieve the 'Everyone' ACL whenever I create a new computer in the domain by code.

Note :
1. I am not asking for code, I want to understand how to achieve this so any guidance/articles will be greatly appreciated as I just seem to be unable to find any articles related to my case.
2. I am using Visual Basic to achieve this in Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks for any replies in advance, looking forward to learning this. :)

Edit 1 : Found several ways that might achieve this : powershell or group policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative for VB.net

The following Visual Basic example shows how to read a security descriptor on an object.

```
Imports ActiveDS
Imports System.Collections

Dim ent As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=ComputerName,OU=container,DC=domain,DC=com")
Dim sd As SecurityDescriptor = CType(ent.Properties("ntSecurityDescriptor").Value,SecurityDescriptor)
Dim acl As AccessControlList = CType(sd.DiscretionaryAcl, AccessControlList) 
Dim ace As AccessControlEntry
For Each ace In  CType(acl, IEnumerable)
   Console.WriteLine("Trustee: {0}", ace.Trustee)
   Console.WriteLine("AccessMask: {0}", ace.AccessMask)
   Console.WriteLine("Access Type: {0}", ace.AceType)
Next ace
```

The following Visual Basic example shows you how to write a security descriptor to an object.

```
Import ActiveDS

Dim usr As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=ComputerName,OU=container,DC=domain,DC=com")
Dim newAce = New AccessControlEntryClass()
Dim usrSD As SecurityDescriptor = CType(usr.Properties("ntSecurityDescriptor").Value, SecurityDescriptor)
Dim usrAcl As AccessControlList = CType(usrSD.DiscretionaryAcl, AccessControlList)
newAce.Trustee = "Anything"
newAce.AccessMask = - 1
newAce.AceType = 0
usrAcl.AddAce(newAce)
usrSD.DiscretionaryAcl = usrAcl
usr.Properties("ntSecurityDescriptor").Value = usrSD
usr.CommitChanges()
```

You have to add reference into the solution. Add Reference --> COM --> Active DS Type Library